# how to refresh a webpage whenever user switch between tabs or user come back to the tab or browser

Tags: javascript, html, refresh, reload

I need to refresh the webpage refresh every time when a user resume at the page.   actually when user open my website all data retrived and shown to user. when user go outside the browser or switch tabs data remain same so when user come back to my tab or reopen browser i want to reload or refresh the page . so user get updated data every time.

i tried all methods

Comment: What are the methods you tried?

Comment: You can use document.hasFocus().

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to check out about websocket for showing realtime data for the ui. But since your asking how to refresh the page when user come back to the tab this maybe helps using *visibilitychange* events

heres an example:

```
window.addEventListener('visibilitychange', () =>{
    if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') window.location.reload();
    else console.log('user leaves the page')
})
```

the event will trigger when user leaves and enter the page so use if condition to execute your own code if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `document.hasFocus()` method to detect if the user is currently viewing the webpage. To continuously check for changes in the user's focus state, you can use the `setInterval()` method.

Here's the code:

```js
let userIsViewingPage = true;

setInterval(focusChecker, 500);

function focusChecker() {
  if (document.hasFocus()) {
    if (!userIsViewingPage) {
      location.reload();
      userIsViewingPage = true;
    }
  } else {
    userIsViewingPage = false;
  }
}
```

I hope this is helpful to you